# API call error while running GA add-on on Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I encountered an error while running Google Analytics add-on on Google Sheet - here below is the error message when I clicked run report:

API call to analyticsreporting.reports.batchGet failed with error:

> User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.

I tried changing the parameters and reached out to Google Analytics support, but there were still no solutions yet.

Anyone would be able to help? Thanks so much.

[image]

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 0):

> User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.

The issue is that the user you have authenticated with does not have access to the universal analytics account you are trying to connect to.

You need to use a user who has read access or you need to Grant that user read access.

Comment: I'm using my account to run the reports and my account should have the admin access already, would you have any idea how I could configure/check my access right? Thanks again

Comment: And your 100% sure your trying to connect to a Universal analytics account and not a GA4 account?

Comment: Yes yes, the property is still under UA but not GA4

Comment: Then I would authorize the user again, make sure your logged in with the correct user.  or doubled check the view id.